# glusterfs uid/gid mapping on Debian Wheezy

Tags: glusterfs, mapping, uid

So I setup a glusterfs volume and it works all fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to mount it with permissions other than root.  Supposedly there's options like translate-uid that can be configured for a volume, but that option doesn't appear to exist on Debian's stock glusterfs 3.2.7.

Does anyone know how to do this?  I tried a chown on the mount point, and that works fine except that the user id mapping on machine 1 does not equate to the user id mapping on machine 2.  Also, this approach doesn't really work with /etc/fstab (from what I know).

Answer (score 0):

I worked around that problem with ACLs:

https://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Access%20Control%20Lists/

Comment: you might want to add the essential parts of the link to your answer, making the answer valid when the link will not be anymore.